# Simple Delphi XE5 PC to Android messaging at runtime over usb

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

I want a simple way to send messages from my Delphi XE5 PC app to my Delphi XE5 Android app over the USB cable. I had thought that using files stored in internal or external Android storage would work, but I can't seem to get the 2 ends to see the other's files.

Is it possible for a XE5 PC app to write a file to a USB connected android's external storage sd card? Then is it possible for an XE5 android app to read that file.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Do you mean real-time communication between PC and Android? Unlikely; for Android, it requires Google's own USB driver for PC and support built in to Android itself; you could write your own USB driver. For passing static data, you can use a shared folder on the external SD card; use [TPath.GetPublicPath](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.GetPublicPath) on Android to find the proper location, and configure your app at setup to use it. Better to use Indy and TCP/IP over wireless, though.

Comment: The PC won't have wireless or network support.

Comment: The static data written into a file (by the PC) onto the external SD is what I'm trying to get working. GetPublicPath returns /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.embarcadero.p1/files. The tablet is connected via a USB cable, and Explorer can see that path as Computer\AT270\External storage\mnt\sdcard\Android\data\com.embarcadero.p1\files. But I can not see the files the android app puts there, with Explorer, and more importantly, the android app can't see the files I cut/paste in there with Explorer. Am I having a '/' vs '\' issue ?

Comment: I doubt that's what it is, as TPath should take care of making the proper conversions on the two sides. It's going to be this evening before I can look into this (no ability to work with Android during the day at my office), but I'll take a peek tonight if you don't have an answer by then.

Comment: Thanks very much for helping. I'll continue to explore the issue.

Comment: If I have a PC app and use a TOpenDialog to browse to a file on the android external storage (Computer\AT270\External storage\NewDir\xx.text) the path returned by TOpenDialog is a temporary file (C:\Users\...\appdata\local\microsoft\windows\Temporary internet file\contentIE5\p6wghdqo\xx[1].test) Does that provide a hint ?

Comment: I have restated the question .....

Comment: After spending a good week trying to implement the 'simple' files based approach, I gave up due to too many 'bugs' somewhere in the process. I was able to get an Indy FTP solution up and running in a half day. Go figure.